# How to do a request "select article where title = "x" " with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to get the ownerID of article

> where article.title = actualTitle (<-- I use a loop the iterate over each article on the page)

But it sounds impossible or I'm just not in the right way. This is my JavaScript

```
'click #showMesArticles'(event){
  var id = Meteor.userId();
  title = "";
  $('.titreArticle').each(function(i, obj) {
    title= obj.textContent;
    var art =  Articles.find({titre: title });
    alert("art.titre: "+ art.titre);
  });
 },
});
```

And if I look art is an [object Object] and art.titre is undefined

Someone could help me please ?

Comment: `find` returns a cursor not an object! try `findOne`!

Comment: It show me the same things than before [object Object] @Elya

Comment: Yep the solution is the one of @Mohsen89z thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[object Object]` that returns from `Articles.find` is actually a [MongoDB Cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/), which doesn't contain the data on itself.

So to get the data from this cursor you need to do a `fetch` in to the cursor.

```
const articles = Articles.find({title: 'x'}).fetch()
console.log(articles)
```

You can explore more on the [Meteor Docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find).

Comment: Thank you for the help so now I know 2 ways to do the job ! Thank's

Answer (score 0):

If someone is trying to do that the solution is the one of @Mohsen89z and you need to use `findOne`

```
'click #showMesArticles'(event){
  var id = Meteor.userId();
  title = "";
  $('.titreArticle').each(function(i, obj) {
    title= obj.textContent;
    var art =  Articles.findOne({titre: title });
    alert("art.titre: "+ art.titre);
  });
 },
});
```